# find sql profiler in visual studio 2015 express

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-profiler

I'm getting an error when updating the database in a C# project in Visual Studio and someone suggested I used SQL profiler.  I am in Visual Studio 2015 Express version, but can't find this anywhere.  Where would I find it or how can I add it to my Visual Studio?

Comment: maybe use 180 day version of commercial server?

Comment: It's not available in express?